# Return fixed number of items from a directory in reverse alphabetical order

Tags: opendir

I have files in directories that are labeled by date (eg, 2012-07-05.xls, 2012-07-04.xls) and I want only to list (and link) the last 10 files in that directory, starting with the newest one. I can generate the list easily in the proper order, but can't figure out how to limit it to 10 (and also not return an "." and ".." entry for the directories).

Here's what I have now. Open to all suggestions.

```
<?php
$path = $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]."/path/";
$dh = @opendir($path);

$files = array();
while (false !== ($file = readdir($dh))) {
            array_push($files, $file);
        }

rsort($files);
foreach ($files as $file){
    echo "<li><a href=\"$file\">";
    echo($file)."</a></li>";

}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use [scandir](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) you can add a sorting parameter as second argument. Then you can just splice the array with [array_slice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) to get the elements you want.

$array = scandir($path);
   $files = array_slice($array, 0, 10);

to get the files you want or skip the first 2 elements because of the . and .. you can do array_slice($array, 2, 10);